# Mongoose static function that uses .find() returns query and static function is not a recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so i have declared a schema and provided a static function to it that search for a user by Email in the file below :

**./database.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/investDB', { useNewUrlParser: true })

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
})

UserSchema.statics.findByEmail = function (email) {
      return this.find({email: email })
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
module.exports = User
```

and called after by an other file

**./fonctions.js**

```
var mongooseModel = require('./database')

function loginAlreadyExist(emailInput) {
  var onDataBase = new mongooseModel()
  return onDataBase.findByEmail(emailInput)
}

exports.loginAlreadyExist = loginAlreadyExist
```

after useing the static function i get the following Error

> onDataBase.findByEmail is not a function

after that i decided to see what the findByEmail returns in the first place so i added `console.log(User.findByEmail("a@a"))` just before the **./database.js** file export.

while i'm expecting an output similar to the schema defined i get a query instade that doesn't contain any of the information even if the mail existe

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  mongooseCollection: 
   NativeCollection {
     collection: null,
     opts: 
      { bufferCommands: true,
        capped: false,
        '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
     name: 'users',
     collectionName: 'users',
     conn: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],

....
options: {},
  _conditions: { email: 'a@a' },
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: 
   NodeCollection {
     collection: 
      ....
     collectionName: 'users' },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true }
```

so her i'm in front of 2 problems,

1) why the static fonction is not recognized
2) why is the findByEmail output doesn't respect the schema (or the collection structured in mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bracket missing:

```
UserSchema.statics.findByEmail = function (email) {
    return this.find({email: email })
}
```

Also you get the result of the query in a callback function on find():

```
UserSchema.statics.findByEmail = function (email) {
    let data;
    this.find({email: email }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        data = result;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: my bad, that was a copy past mistake, i corrected it but it was not the source of my problem, cuz otherwise i would have an other error message. but you'r right my mistake for not paying attention to the copy past

Comment: @El.KIbrahim I edited my answer, you can get the result of find in a callback function.

Comment: i see what you did there, but apparently the variable data doesn't update when called in the callback, plus the thing that i don't undrestand is the result ifself not where does the query came from, normaly the returned output should be an Array following the schema defined earlier. i also think that the callback is unnecessary i'll just try catch it, but for the simplicity purpose i just made a return

Answer (score 0):

**In your model**

```html
UserSchema.statics.findByEmail = function (email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return this.findOne({ email: email }).exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) reject(err)
            resolve(user);
        });
    });
}
```